# BigQuery: extract date from datetime with timezone

Tags: datetime, google-bigquery

I am trying to return a column in BigQuery with the extracted date from the column *start_time*.

The values in the column are of the format: 11/27/2019 14:40:15 CET +0100

I've written following code:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DATE FROM TIMESTAMP(start_time))
  AS date
  FROM `cc_raw.cc_exp`
```

However I am getting the error message: *Invalid timestamp: '11/27/2019 14:40:15 CET +0100'*

How do I go about here?

Many thanks, 
Janine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  EXTRACT(DATE FROM PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %Z %z', start_time)) AS date
FROM `cc_raw.cc_exp`
```

You use `PARSE_TIMESTAMP` function with `'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %Z %z'` to handle timestamps presented as strings formatted as `'11/27/2019 14:40:15 CET +0100'`

You can do quick test by running below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  EXTRACT(DATE FROM PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %Z %z', '11/27/2019 14:40:15 CET +0100')) AS date
```