# Bigquery cannot parse date from datetime

Tags: google-bigquery

Bigquery cannot parse datetime from a date in spite of providing right format. Dates in my column are of the same format I used in the string:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DATE FROM PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z',"2021-03-22T14:00:00-03:00"))
```

This gives this error:

```
Failed to parse input string "2021-03-22T14:00:00-03:00"
```

I am trying to make this work by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180688)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `%Ez` instead of `%z` as in below

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DATE FROM PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Ez',"2021-03-22T14:00:00-03:00"))
```

See [Supported format elements for TIMESTAMP](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#supported_format_elements_for_timestamp) for more details